# Best Open Source Silverlight Ribbon and Docking Implmenetation

Tags: silverlight

I love DiveElements' SandDock and SandRibbon.

http://www.divelements.com/net/controls/sanddocksl/

http://www.divelements.com/net/controls/sandribbon/

Unfortunately, I can't bundle these in an open-source project.

Can anyone suggest the best open-source Silverlight ribbon and docking implementations please?

For docking, I'd like it to be like VS, being able to pin and move panels around in various layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following which I think are good enough for what I need.

• Blacklight’s Drag Dock Panel - http://blacklight.codeplex.com/ - Not a VS-style full-featured dock, but good enough to present multiple tabs in a variety of layouts.

• Win Toolbar - http://wintoolbar.codeplex.com/ - not resizable, but looks good.